# How to insert the list in the text widget using python

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a list containing 10 words.
I want to display all those 10 words in Text widget.

This is my coding:

```
self._ui.textBrowser_2.append(pos)
```

pos is the name of the list which contains 10 words.
but, it throws me error. 
"QTextEdit.append(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'"

How to rectify this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot display a list in a Text widget. Perhaps you could join the elements together as a string and display them using:

```
self._ui.textBrowser_2.append('\n'.join(pos))
```

`'\n'.join(some_list)` takes the elements of the list `some_list` and joins the elements into a string separated by the specified character, in this case a newline ('\n')

### Examples

```
>>> test = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print ''.join(test)
abc

>>> print ' '.join(test)
a b c

>>> '#'.join(test)
'a#b#c'

>>> print ', '.join(test)
a, b, c

>>> print '\n'.join(test)
a
b
c
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the list object displayed in the text widget now. but all those words occur in a single line. I want them to be displayed one by one in text widget. How to do that ??

Comment: @user3177433, What do you mean by "one by one". Do you mean newlines?

Comment: yes., when one list object is displayed then the next new object should be printed in the new line

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the `append` function expects a `QString` as its argument. Python lists are not strings. You can use `join` to make a string from a list.

```
words = ' '.join(pos) # replace ' ' with whatever you want between the words
self._ui.textBrowser_2.append(words)
```